# Regex SQL syntax in bash

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

My problem is the following- I have file with SQL syntax in it. For example content of `sql.txt`:

```sql
select a,b from
x.tabl where A;

select b,c from x.tabl
;
select c,d from x.tabl where B;
Select d from
tabl
;
select z from x.table;
Select a,b from x.tabl_3;
```

Now what I want to do is to rewrite this file in bash, replacing all `x.tabl` and `tabl` with `y.rtabl` (new name differs only by name prefix and db).

So expected output is:

```sql
select a,b from
y.rtabl where A;

select b,c from y.rtabl
;
select c,d from y.rtabl where B;
Select d from
y.rtabl
;
select z from x.table;
Select a,b from x.tabl_3;
```

what I've got so far:

```sh
eval "sed -e 's/x.tabl/y.rtabl/' sql.txt>copysql.txt"
eval "mv copysql.txt sql.txt"
eval "sed -e 's/tabl/y.rtabl/' sql.txt>copysql.txt"
eval "mv copysql.txt sql.txt"
```

Or

```sh
eval "sed -e 's/\Wx.tabl\W/ y.rtabl /' sql.txt>copysql.txt"
eval "mv copysql.txt sql.txt"
eval "sed -e 's/\Wtabl\W/ y.rtabl /' sql.txt>copysql.txt"
eval "mv copysql.txt sql.txt"
```

The `mv` part works quite neatly for me, but `sed` requires some serious tuning.

Comment: You can omit the `mv` command by using seds `-i ''` option

Comment: `sed -i` is an inexplicable, non-standard extension to do what `ed` already does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `eval` here. Just use

```
sed -E 's/(^|[[:space:]]+)(x\.)?tabl(;|$|[[:space:]]+)/\1y.rtabl\3\4/g' \
  sql.txt > copysql.txt && mv copysql.txt sql.txt
```

---

- `(^|[[:space:]]+)` matches either the beginning of the line or arbitrary whitespace preceding the table name to match
- `(x\.)?tabl` matches `tabl` preceded by an optional `x_`.
- `(;|$|[[:space:]]+)` matches either the end of a statement, the end of a line or arbitrary whitespace.

Together, these three regular expressions will match `tabl` or `x_tabl` and any whitespace wrapped around it, and replace it with `y.rtabl` and whatever surrounding whitespace was captured.

Note that this uses POSIX extended regular expressions, so will work with any POSIX-compliant version of `sed`. Some implementations (notably GNU `sed`) may allow substantially shorter solutions, especially where they support matching a word boundary.

Comment: That solves half of the problem- I don't want to replace 2 last sql-s (so don't touch ```x.table``` and ```x.tabl_3```).

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to find a way to address that without requiring extensions to standard `sed`/`ed`. Do you know what version of `sed` you are using, if you can rely on that?

Comment: Updated with a working version that only assumes POSIX extended regular expressions (which eliminates `ed` as an option).

Comment: Updated to handle the case where the table occurs immediately before a `;`, something not appearing in the sample input.

Comment: Thanks, this works, and it's exactly what I was hoping for!

Comment: Keep in mind, though, this makes some pretty significant assumptions about what is in the file. Something like `select c, d from x.tabl where foo = "x.tabl;"` will be mishandled. You simply can't parse a non-regular language with regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Python solution:

**sql_replace.py**

```
import re
with open("sql.txt") as f:
    sql = f.read()

sql = re.sub(r"\bx\.tabl\b", "y.rtabl", sql)
sql = re.sub(r"\btabl\b", "y.rtabl", sql)

with open("sql_new.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(sql)
```

---

[Python Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/81c1daca5c)

---

Run `python sql_replace.py` on the same dir as `sql.txt` and a new file named `sql_new.txt` will be created containing:

```
select a,b from
y.rtabl where A;

select b,c from y.rtabl
;
select c,d from y.rtabl where B;
Select d from
y.rtabl
;
select z from x.table;
Select a,b from x.tabl_3;
```

---

Note:

The regexes are pretty simple, but `\b` ([word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)) is a must, so `x.table` and `x.tabl_3` don't get replaced.

Comment: I was going to write, that python also would do :) thanks, this works!

Comment: You're welcome. I choose python for the simplicity of the regex construction. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Is this good enough :

```
sed -E "s/(x[.]tabl($| )|tabl($| ))/NEWTABLE /g" input.txt
```

Output

```
select a,b from
NEWTABLE where A;

select b,c from NEWTABLE 
;
select c,d from NEWTABLE where B;
Select d from
NEWTABLE 
;
select z from x.table;
Select a,b from x.tabl_3;
```

Regards!

Comment: I don't want to replace table names in 2 last sql-s. It's different table.

Comment: Hm, it doesn't capture 3rd sql from the bottom- I don't have white space after ```tabl```

Answer (score 0):

To overwrite sql.txt in-place do:

```
sed -i'' 's/\(x.\)\?tabl\>/y.rtabl/g' sql.txt
```

Changes to OP sed command:

- Remove `eval`
- escape dots `\.` in pattern
- do global replacement
- use `tabl\>` instead of `tabl` for exact match

Comment: Thanks, it solves part of the problem. The other part is not to touch 2 last sql-s i.e. ```x.tabl_3``` and ```x.table```.

Comment: I don't want to replace neither ```tabl_3``` nor ```table```, only ```tabl``` and ```x.tabl```